# MacBook Pro Laptop toolbar in all programs freeze up...can't use; even on the web and the apple itself. I have to restart after 20 min. to use again

Tags: keyboard, performance, garageband

I have had a MacBook Pro for a little over a year.  Ever since I've had it, I can work in any app for 20 minutes and then I won't be able to open any option on the toolbar, like "Edit", "tool", etc.  I have to use spacebar to start and stop and shortcuts.  It's the same way on the web and even the apple toolbar.

I've contacted Apple Support on numerous occasions and they can't seem to solve it.  I have the same problem when it's in safe mode, too.  I would like to resolve this without having to restart my laptop every 20 to 30 minutes!

Is anybody else experiencing this problem?  I've Googled it several different ways, checked on YouTube, ask.com, but it seems like I'm the only person with this problem. (But I don't believe that.)

Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: I know it's no help to you but ... I'd have returned the machine long before the one-year anniversary of purchasing it approached, and asked for a replacement.  Maybe you are lucky enough that the machine is still covered by a warranty?

Comment: We would need a lot more info. What exact mac, what exact software (both OS and apps) are running? Also whats the "apple toolbar".

Comment: Spacebar to start and stop what? I agree that I would definitely take it back to the shop for them to assess.